How to define container_names for services launched using kamal
How to define container_names for ruby on rails services (app, sidekiq) launched using kamal
docker had a container_name element to mention the name of the container.
container_name is a string that specifies a custom container name, rather than a name generated by default.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/05-services/#container_name
